# Redis lua script: will my attempt to mix KEYS and generated keys within the script work when clustering (if I'm careful)?

Tags: c#, redis, lua, stackexchange.redis, redis-cluster

I've searched for an answer to this, and every question doesn't really capture what I am asking.

I'm using StackExchange.Redis as a redis client in C# to maintain state in a redis cache that has potential to be clustered in future.

I'm trying to use lua scripting to atomically manage sets of data - the combined contents of the sets and other associated keys is combined to build state information (I can't currently rely on RedisJSON to be available for complex data).

To achieve this, I have a lua script that searches for information in a set, and uses the result to build a key dynamically to then add information to maintain other keys.

As Stackexchange.Redis will automatically find the correct node to execute the script on using the KEYS that are passed to the script, I was wondering whether I can actually mix the two to ensure that my script is cluster-safe.

I've arranged my keys so that all keys within the script are in the same hash slot:

```
{MyServiceName:id}
```

For example:

```
redis.call SADD '{MyServiceName:1}:namespaces', @namespace
redis.call SADD '{MyServiceName:1}:namespace:' .. @ns .. 'providers', @providerId
```

Note that this is a simplified example - I could potentially pass all the keys in here as KEYS, but that would be duplicating the keys and the data

What I've done is the following:

```
(PerformOperation.lua)
-- Accept a dummy key that is in the same hash slot - this will ensure we are on the correct cluster node?
local idKey = @idKey

-- Do the rest of the stuff with only keys of the same hash slot
redis.call SADD '{MyServiceName:' .. @id .. '}:namespaces', @namespace

...
(C# caller)
this.performOperationScript= this.LoadScript("PerformOperation.lua");

...

// The idKey defines the hash slot, for example {MyServiceName:1}
var result = await this.performOperationScript.EvaluateAsync(db, new { idKey= $"{{MyServiceName:{id}}}", id });
```

Will this achieve what I hope it will, which is that Stackexchange.Redis will forward the script to the correct cluster node based on idKey, and then as long as any keys I generate within the script are in the same hash slot, everything should work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis use KEYS to calculate slot when using lua. So if you only have a single IDKey as keys, it will all map to the correct node.

And you keys are dynamic and you use hash tag, it will works as you want.